# "Object has no attribute" when executing RunPython in django migration

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to run this operation:

```py
def apply_func(apps, schema_editor):
    User = apps.get_model("accounts", "User")
    for user in User.objects.all():
        if user.is_two_fa_enabled:
            user.is_verified = True
            user.save()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='user',
            name='is_verified',
            field=models.BooleanField(default=False),
        ),
        migrations.RunPython(apply_func)
    ]
```

but I've no idea why am I getting such an error `AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'is_two_fa_enabled'` when I want to migrate.

```py
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    two_fa_type = models.CharField(choices=TwoFaTypes.choices, default=TwoFaTypes.SMS.value, max_length=32, null=True)
    
    @property
    def is_two_fa_enabled(self):
        return bool(self.two_fa_type)
```

Could you please explain me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The historic model does not have the properties defined in the class, so `is_two_fa_enabled` can not be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The historic model does not have the properties defined in the class, so `is_two_fa_enabled` can not be used.

```
def apply_func(apps, schema_editor):
    User = apps.get_model('accounts', 'User')
    for user in User.objects.all():
        if user.two_fa_type:
            user.is_verified = True
            user.save()
```

or more effective:

```
from django.db.models import Q

def apply_func(apps, schema_editor):
    User = apps.get_model('accounts', 'User')
    User.objects.filter(
        ~Q(two_fa_type=None), ~Q(two_fa_type='')
    ).update(is_verified=True)
```